# How can I get the flash to work in liveview mode on my Canon 70D?

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash, live-view

I have a Canon 70D with a Canon Speedlite 580EX II.

This may be a duplicate question, but I can't find the answer.

I can't get the flash to go off in live view mode, either the external flash or the pop up flash.  Is this a setting within the camera that I need to adjust in order for the flash to fire?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the flash isn't triggering is because you have silent shutter activated on your camera.

To disable it on your 70D please go to the Camera 2 Tab of your menu and then change the Silent LV Shoot setting to disable.
http://web.canon.jp/imaging/eos70dshootingguide/function/index.html

Have a look at these different articles:
http://martybugs.net/blog/blog.cgi/gear/lights/Triggering-Flashes-While-Using-LiveView.html
http://www.p4pictures.com/2011/02/live-view-mode-and-flash-on-your-eos-dslr/

*Edit*

Normally Canon speedlite disable the Silent shutter. However your flash model is 6years older than the camera so it might not have that feature.